# Как предоставить доступ к репозиторию третьему лицу?

Tags: git, github

Подскажите пожалуйста у меня есть репозиторий на гитхабе, хочу в команду взять разработчика, нужно ли мне делиться ним паролем чтоб он мог пушить в свою ветку и как мне закрыть ветку мастер чтоб только один я мог ее менять ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Паролем делится точно не нужно. Это очень плохо. И в этом случае точно  будет сложно запретить пушить или что то ещё.

На гитхабе есть инструкция https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository

Если очень кратко - попросите его зарегистрироваться, узнайте ник/логин, потом в настройках свого проекта в " Manage access" найдите "Invite a collaborator."

Вот здесь описаны разные настройки прав https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository#collaborator-access-for-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account

скорее всего, вначале просто просите делать через форк+pull request, в этом случае у Вас будет много контроля и не нужно будет давать много доступов. То есть, даже не нужно будет добавлять к своему проекту, главное, что бы мог форкнуть.